# Como agregar un diccionario a otro diccionario y luego ese ultimo a una lista

Tags: python

Debo agregar un diccionario llamado transacciones a otro diccionario llamado bloques que ese debe ir agregado a una lista, me encuentro muy confundido y no logro comprender lógicamente como podría hacer eso. Aun no tengo código de ejemplo porque estoy muy perdido.

La lógica que se debe aplicar es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí tengo lo que mas o menos entendí, cargar el archivo agregar los datos y las demás funciones hacen como su nombre lo indica.

```py
import csv

def cargar_blockchain_cupicoin (ruta_archivo: str) -> list:
    blockchain = []
    archivo = open("C:/Users/John James/Desktop/rosa/esqueleto")
    titulos = archivo.readline().split(",")
    linea_info_bloques = archivo.readline()
    print(titulos)
    while len(linea_info_bloques) < 0:
        datos = linea_info_bloques.split(",")
        codigo_bloques = datos[0]
        numero_bloque = datos[1]
        remitente =  datos[2]
        destinatario =  datos[3]
        valor = datos[4]
        if destinatario == "":
            operacion = "contrato"
        else:
            operacion = "transferencia"
            
        transaccion = crear_transaccion(codigo_bloques, remitente, destinatario, valor, operacion)
        agregar_transaccion(bloques, transaccion)
        timestamp = datos[5]
        cantidad_trans = None
        
def crear_transaccion (codigo_bloques: str, remitente:str, destina: str, valor: int, operacion: str)-> dict:
    transaccion = {"codigo_transaccion": codigo, "remitente": remitente, "destinatario": destina, "valor": valor, "operacion": operacion}
    return transaccion 

#def cantidad_transacciones ()     

#Esta funcion creo que esta mal, porque hay que agregar la trasacion al ultima posicion del bloque.
def agregar_transaccion (blockchain: list, transaccion: dict) -> dict:
    ult_bloque = blockchain[-1]
    posicion_trans = ult_bloque["cantidad_transacciones"]
    for posicion in range (0, posicion_trans):
        ult_bloque[posicion] = transaccion
    return ult_bloque
```

Comment: Buenas, si sería recomendable que pusieras el código más que nada para realmente entender bien la pregunta y qué elementos agregar luego a la lista si las claves, los valores o ambos. Anímate y pon el código como tú lo harías o querrías hacerlo

Comment: Replantea el problema en términos de **contenidos**: qué tienes en "transacciones", qué hay en "bloques" y que contiene la lista. Sin una descripción de cada cosa cualquier respuesta será un engendro.

Comment: Lo realizare, para poderlo mostrar. Muchas gracias ♥

Comment: Ya agregue lo que he realizado mas una imagen donde explica la lógica como se debe realizar, me encantaría poder entender pero me es confuso algunas cosas

Comment: Tengo dos cosas que decirte. Primero, si quieres agregar un elemento al final de la lista puedes usar el método append. Segundo, te recomiendo evitar usar split(',') para separar campos de csvs, pues que pasaría si una de las cadenas del csv tiene una coma? como `'hola, mundo',2,3`. El split te lo separaría como `["'hola", " mundo'", 2, 3]`. Puedes usar [expresiones regulares](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html) para evitar esto. O mejor! [Un modulo ya pensado para leer csvs](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/csv.html). De hecho, importas ese modulo pero no lo usas...

Comment: Sobre lo del append, un ejemplo sería `ult_bloque.append(valor)`.

Comment: ¿Tienes un diccionario `transaccion` que quieres añadir a otro diccionario `bloque` y este último a una lista `blockchain`?. Pues haces `bloque[n] = transaccion`  y después `blockchain.append(transaccion)`. El valor de `n` depende de tu caso (en tu figura sería `1`)